# File is showing Open Read-Only while opening the file

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a .xlsx file using XSSFWorkBook in Java.
Using below code I'm trying

```
try
{
    File tempFile = new File(validateFileUrl);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    if(!rowList.isEmpty()) // rowList contains comma(,) separated string values
    {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        int rownum=0;
        for(String rowStr : rowList)
        {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            String[] cellArr = rowStr.split(",");
            int cellCount=0;
            for(String cellStr : cellArr)
            {
                XSSFCell crrCell = row.createCell(cellCount++);
                crrCell.setCellValue(cellStr);
            }
        }
        
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        workbook.write(fos);
        workbook.close();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

file got created successfully, but the problem is that created file is opening in Read only mode, How can I create this in writeable mode?

I have tried the below option also

```
tempFile.setWritable(true);
```

but its not working, please help on this. Thanks

Comment: I tried with your code and the resulting excel sheet is editable for me

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian I tried this code in a Java Spring boot Micro service, If I stop the service I can able to edit that. I can't able to edit while the service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix is to close the FileOutputStream object

```
fos.close();
```

**Sample Code:**

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Excel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String validateFileUrl = "so-excel.xlsx";
        List<String> rowList = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
        try
        {
            File tempFile = new File(validateFileUrl);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
            XSSFSheet sheet = null;
            if(!rowList.isEmpty()) // rowList contains comma(,) separated string values
            {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                sheet = workbook.createSheet();
                int rownum=0;
                for(String rowStr : rowList)
                {
                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                    String[] cellArr = rowStr.split(",");
                    int cellCount=0;
                    for(String cellStr : cellArr)
                    {
                        XSSFCell crrCell = row.createCell(cellCount++);
                        crrCell.setCellValue(cellStr);
                    }
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                workbook.write(fos);
                System.out.println("Workbook created!!");
                workbook.close();
                fos.close(); //To close the FileOutputStream object
                System.out.println("File Output Stream closed!!");
            }
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(600000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel will not allow editing a file that some other application is still writing. Instead it is waiting for exclusive access.

You need to ensure in Java the file buffer gets closed when you are finished writing the file. This happens either when the JVM terminates or when your code explicitly closes the FileOutputStream. Note that explicitly calling close can be tricky in case exceptions get thrown. Here is a safe way that makes use of the AutoClose feature of FileOutputStream:

```
try {
    File tempFile = new File(validateFileUrl);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    if(!rowList.isEmpty()) { // rowList contains comma(,) separated string values 
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        int rownum=0;
        for(String rowStr : rowList) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            String[] cellArr = rowStr.split(",");
            int cellCount=0;
            for(String cellStr : cellArr) {
                XSSFCell crrCell = row.createCell(cellCount++);
                crrCell.setCellValue(cellStr);
            }
        }
    
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
            workbook.write(fos);
        }
        workbook.close();
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that vice versa, Excel is exclusively holding access to the file. So if you want to write it again from your application, ensure Excel has closed the document.